# Visual Studio 2022 ( Window for Code ) not Working

Tags: ide, refactoring, intellisense, code-completion

Version:
Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit) - Current
Version 17.8.3 (windows 10)

The Code editor Window behaves strangely, does not work at all.

The same Solution / Project if open in my Laptop Ide is working, if in the Desk-Top is not working.

Code is with different color, Auto competition not working, refactoring not working, In short it is unusable.
Dose not matter if i work on a Console App or Blazor server, the Window for coding dose not work.
Menu are working.

What i did:

1. Clean, Rebuild, Build the Solution.
2. Clean, Rebuild, Build the Project.
3. Start Visual Studio Installer and REPAIR.
4. Restart the machine.
   Still not working

[image: strange]

Some Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I probably understood what happened.
On the project I usually work with the desk top, when I'm not in the office I continue with the laptop.
For some reason a issue arose and a file was duplicated (Index.razor to Index_copy.razor).
This situation probably created some conflict.
After deleting the copy and cleaning and rebuilding the project everything worked again.